# what's the practice to send "keepalive packet"

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I saw that some NAT route will drop connection automatically if no packet is sent out in some period.

Howevere KeepAlie option in TCP only send packet every 2 hours (On Windows), do we need to send out "keepalive" packet every now and then?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 2000 and later, you can use the [SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220.aspx) control code to set both the keep-alive timeout and the keep-alive interval on a per-connection basis.